# How to generate all possible values in an array where [x] >= [x+1]?

Tags: design-patterns, series

I'm attempting to write an algorithm that takes an array of size n and generating all possible combinations of integer values up to size max where the number in position x is greater than or equal to x+1.

So for an array of size 4 and max of 5:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0}
{4, 3, 2, 1}
{2, 2, 0, 0}
{5, 5, 5, 5}
```

Are all acceptable values.

```
{0, 1, 2, 3}
{0, 3, 0, 0}
{6, 6, 6, 6}
```

Are invalid.

For an array of size 4 and max of 1 this would be all the possible combinations:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0}
{1, 0, 0, 0}
{1, 1, 0, 0}
{1, 1, 1, 0}
{1, 1, 1, 1}
```

I just can't seem to get my head around how to implement it for any value for max. So I'm asking you guys if you could give me a hand :D

Is there a name for these series?

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I can't wrap my head around it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out, no recursion necessary.

I'm posting the answer for anyone else who's looking for the answer for the question I asked.

```
public static void next(int[] data)
{
    final int arrayLen = data.length;
    int lowestIndex = 0;
    int lowestValue = data[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < arrayLen; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] < lowestValue)
        {
            lowestValue = data[i];
            lowestIndex = i;
        }
    }

    data[lowestIndex]++;

    for (int j = lowestIndex + 1; j < arrayLen; j++)
    {
        data[j] = 0;
    }
}
```

It iterates through the entire array and finds the first occurance of the smallest value. That value is incremented by one and resets all values after it to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you having problems? Hint: recursion is your friend (you can use recursion for nested loops where the nesting level is determined only at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

Have a subroutine that takes n and max and returns a set of arrays.

If n > 1, it calls itself recursively with n-1 instead, and for each result the recursive call returned, generates one or more arrays with an additional leftmost element varying between the previous leftmost element and max.

If n is 1, it returns max+1 1-element arrays containing values from 0 to max.